# Windows Program fails to open file

Tags: permissions, wine, files

I´ve just installed SONAR LE 8.5.1 on my Ubuntu 12.10 machine. And, against my expectations, it works complete fine! Except for one thing:

When I record something, SONAR is getting the audio-data and can save it correctly to a .wav file (`C:\Cakewalk Projects\#Project-Name#\#File#.wav` what equals `/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Cakewalk Projects/#Project Name#/#File#.wav`).
I can play the recorded stuff with any audio-player and the file is set to 775 permissions.
BUT: When i then press play / record in SONAR, it tells me

> Failed to open `C:\Cakewalk Projects\#Project Name#\#File#.wav`

When saving the project, closing the application and opening it up again it tells me

> Some audio files were not found and are replaced with silence.

As it says, the recorded file is then "empty" or "silent" even though it exists.

Changing the folder/file permissions to 777 did not help :/ Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance for taking care of this :)

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like your special characters in the filename string.

Comment: Tghe Program itself is putting `(),-`'s in the filename, that sadly cannot be avoided :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, mdpc was right, it was a problem of the filename. The strange thing is:

The Project-Name (and with that the Folder-Name) may not contain special characters but spaces. But it is completely ok if the files have special characters, e.g.
`C:\Cakewalk Projects\My Project(Testing)\My Project(Testing), Voclas, Rec (8).wav`
will NOT work, where as
`C:\Cakewalk Projects\My Project Testing\My Project Testing, Voclas, Rec (8).wav`
will work.